# Multiplication or if: what is more efficient?

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm

I have a binary image (size: 100x100) of a hand, that we can represent as a matrix composed only by 0 or 1 values. This is an example:

[image: Example of a binary image of a human hand]

Assuming that I have an array of `double` representing the linearized image, and that we call it `image`, I need to perform the following operations:

```
double accumulator = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < image.Length; ++j)
{
    accumulator += image[j] * weights[j];
}
```

In other words, I need to calculate the weighted sum of each pixel of the `image` array. `weights` represents an array that contains `double` values, and it is used to weight each pixel of the image.

Is the following code more efficient than the previous one?

```
double accumulator = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < image.Length; ++j)
{
    if (image[j] != 0)
    {
        accumulator += image[j] * weights[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Run both and see for yourself.

Comment: If it was all non-0s it would clearly be slower. If it was all 0s it would likely be a lot faster. Where the lines cross is anyone's guess. :) I recommend Stopwatch and lots of trials with different bitmaps! If you even need to bother...

Comment: For the size of 100x100, if there is any difference at all, the difference will not be very significant. Unless you are dealing with many of such images, or the images may be bigger (millions of pixels), then there might be appreciable difference.

Comment: Setting aside the premature optimization issue (so that there is something to discuss), branching can introduce various potential delays at the processor level, depending on whether the branches are readily predictable.  The effect is processor-dependent and the magnitude of the effect is not likely to be very noticeable here.

Comment: I ask the above question only to comprehend if the 'if' instruction is slow as a multiplication... The correct answer is 'it is impossible to say'. It's right?

Comment: @VitoShadow, it's not impossible to say for this specific case (though the more general question in your comment, yes, that's insufficiently constrained); you can certainly measure the performance.  From there, it's appropriate to follow up with the question 'why is this version more performant than that version?'  Without data, though, you're right, it's all just speculation.

Comment: In modern processors (such as recent Intel and ARM class), "if" is likely to be slower than multiplication (especially if it is actually an unpredictable branch).  However, either should be fast enough to make memory bandwidth a likely bottleneck -- e.g., if most of a large image is 0, you might gain some speed from not needing to load the weights.

Comment: In black and white with only 0 or 1 values store the picture in a byte array instead of double array and use;                    double accumulator = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < image.Length; ++j)
{
    if (image[j]==1) accumulator += weights[j];
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is - you really don't need to be worrying about this at this juncture.  If your code is running *too* slow, then you can experiment with some optimization.  However, "too slow" is subjective.

**Premature Optimization Is The Root Of All Evil**.

As angelatlarge points out, for the moment - go with what is easily readable, and easily maintainable.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, absolutely.  I optimized my typing prematurely.  Shame on me. :)

Comment: Hehe, well we can delete these comments now :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice: Mmmm... I agree with you in principle, but the question wan't "what is the Root Of All Evil?"... rather it was "which method is more efficient"... It seems like OP is "entitled" to an answer on that.

Comment: @angelatlarge, the problem is that one could easily find this out through simple experimentation as Jason Watkins suggested in the comments.  Over 100x100, I very much doubt there's going to be any noticeable difference.  My worry is, is that the developer is concentrating on what is currently a non-existent problem (in my eyes, admittedly).  Increase the image resolution to 2000x2000 and try and get it to do 1000 attempts in under 5 seconds due to a business requirement... then we can start looking at optimization, or even moving it out of C# altogether :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice I completely agree that the OP could have done some more work before asking the question (though even then, some C# expert might have chimed in with something like "Many versions of C# have a known issue where array access inside conditionals causes it to scan though the entire array, so you sould avoid that"), but even granting your first point, I guess (to me) a more helpful answer in the same vein might have been "On 100x100 image the two code snippets will perform identically, so keep whichever code you think is easier to read and is more maintainable."

Comment: @angelatlarge, see I think you hit the nail on the head with the "easier to read and maintainable".  I think I will update my answer and vicariously steal that.

Comment: Why does no one use the full quote *We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%. -- Donald Knuth*

Comment: @ConradFrix, a very good point.  Luckily this didn't appear to be the critical 3%  :)